# Trying to run Chef-client without using dependencies of a certain cookbook

Tags: dependency-injection, chef-infra

I have a cookbook that I need to use in another one so I included it in the metadata.rb file and it seemed fine but it is creating an issue where that cookbook had another dependancy that I don't want to use but I can't remove from that cookbook since it is used by a bunch of other applications.

Is there a way to not use the dependancy but only when I include the cookbook I want in my metadata of the one I am trying to build? Hope that makes sense. Tried a few times to make it sound better and each way sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef does not support optional dependencies.